# Question marks in wildcard search in Windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wildcard

I am using wildcard characters (? and *) to search for files in Windows in a c++ program with _tfindfirst64 and _tfindnext64. I observed the following code

```
    TCHAR root[1024] = L"C:/testData/?????_?????.jpg";
    _tfinddata64_t c_file;
    intptr_t hFile = _tfindfirst64(root, &c_file);
    do
    {
        wcout << c_file.name << endl;
    } while (_tfindnext64(hFile, &c_file) == 0);
    _findclose(hFile);
```

picks up the following files:

```
12345_---.jpg
12345_12.jpg
12345_12345.jpg
```

But I was expected the filter would accept only the last one as it means: "5 arbitrary chars followed by '_' followed by another chars with '.jpg'" [as described](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/indexsrv/ms-dos-and-windows-wildcard-characters). What would be the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've found, a `?` in a file search doesn't require a character to be present, but matching will fail if a character is present that your search string doesn't account for. For example, `foo?.txt` will match `foo.txt`, `foo1.txt`, `fooa.txt`, and so on, but will *not* match `foo10.txt` or `foo_abc.txt`.

About the only way I know of to work around this is to re-check the result afterward to assure you eliminate any unwanted matches. In this case, it sounds like just comparing the length of the filename with what you expect will suffice.